# check whether shapes are touching in canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, addeventlistener

I am still a noobie in javascript. I am trying to build a pacman-type game and am struck in trying to figure out how to check whether my avatar is touching the boundary or not. I could design the movement statements so that they only work when when movement is not restricted by walls but that would be messy and inconvenient, especially if i try changing the map every so often.
Any suggestion?
My code is :

```
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,r,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}


function listen() {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 37 : {
        if (x - r > 0) {
          x = x - 2;
        }
        break;
      }
      case 38 : {
        if (y - r > 0) {
          y = y - 2;
        }
        break;
      }
      case 39 : {
        if (x + r < 600) {
          x = x + 2;
        }
        break;
      }
      case 40 : {
        if (y + r < 600) {
          y = y + 2;
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  });
}

var myvar = setInterval(function () { draw() } , 300);
var yourvar = setInterval(function() { listen() }, 1000);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: I suggest you if you wanna rapid speed in developing process try my canvas framework : https://bitbucket.org/nikola_l/visual-js